# pdf2swf Segmentation fault (core dumped) error 139 What's going on?

Tags: segmentation-fault, flexpaper, pdf2swf

I am trying to convert on the fly pdf documents to swf to use with FlexPaper viewer.
When I try to convert Paper.pdf (wich is the pdf bring in the flexpaper example) I got an error 139.

Here is the php code :

```
$command = "/usr/local/bin/pdf2swf Paper.pdf -o Paper.swf -T 9 -f";
exec($command,$output,$return_var);
print_r($output);
print_r($return_var);
```

When i execute these command with verbose mode (-vv) i get this :

NOTICE File contains jpeg pictures [1174] => DEBUG | moveTo -0.70 438.30 [1175] => DEBUG | lineTo -0.70 729.35 [1176] => DEBUG | lineTo 413.35 729.35 [1177] => DEBUG | lineTo 413.35 438.30 [1178] => DEBUG | lineTo -0.70 438.30 [1179] => VERBOSE Drawing 576x405 jpeg-image (id 90) at size 576x405 (414x291), >256 colors [1180] => Segmentation fault (core dumped) ) 139

I try running pdf2swf with "-O 1" and "-O 2" flag. With no success.

With '-O 1' i get :
VERBOSE endPage (GfxOutputDev) [752] => VERBOSE Flushing bitmap (bbox: 56,56,118,89 62x33) (clipped against 0,0,595,841) [753] => VERBOSE Drawing 62x33 image (id 10) at size 62x33 (62x33), 17 colors [754] => Segmentation fault (core dumped) ) 139

and with "-O 2":
endPage (FullBitmapOutputDev) [558] => VERBOSE Flushing bitmap (bbox: 0,56,595,800) [559] => VERBOSE Drawing 595x744 image (id 10) at size 595x744 (595x744), >256 colors [560] => Segmentation fault (core dumped) ) 139

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

This means that the version of `pdf2swf` you are trying to use is buggy.

You should try to build the latest version, and if that still crashes, you can try filing a bug against `pdf2swf`, or debug it yourself.